# Conjugacy classes in PSL(3,q) and PSU(3,q)

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory

What are the conjugacy classes of $PSL (3,q)$ and $PSU(3,q)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is well-known, and there are a number of relevant references. Firstly, there are these by Wall (they are pretty hard to read though).

> Wall, G. E. Conjugacy classes in projective and special linear groups.  Bull. Austral. Math. Soc. 22 (1980), no. 3, 339–364.
>
> Wall, G. E. On the conjugacy classes in the unitary, symplectic and orthogonal groups.
> J. Austral. Math. Soc. 3 1963 1–62.

You might also be interested in this paper which I personally find much more readable.

> Macdonald, I. G.
> Numbers of conjugacy classes in some finite classical groups.
> Bull. Austral. Math. Soc. 23 (1981), no. 1, 23–48.

You could also look at Carter's *Finite groups of Lie type* (email me if you want a copy) although that is a rather hard text and is much more general than you need.

For conjugacy in $PSL_3(q)$ you could also just do a search on *Jordan rational forms* - these forms classify conjugacy in $GL_3(q)$, and this classification can then be adapted to deal with $PSL_3(q)$. [I have a paper with Anupam Singh](http://arxiv.org/abs/0809.4412) in which we describe how to do this (again in much greater generality than you need).

Answer (score 2):

As Nick points out, the classes are well documented in the literature.  An old paper by Frame and Simpson, with free online access
[here](http://cms.math.ca/10.4153/CJM-1973-049-7), 
is a convenient source.    (This paper was in fact reviewed by G.E. Wall.)  Their combined treatment of the groups leads them to mix up the parametrizations a bit in the character tables, but I think the class information is basically reliable.   In any case, the later work on characters inspired by Deligne and Lusztig (as in Carter's 1985 book) has led to a far more thorough treatment, while the cpnjugacy class information has been developed uniformly for all finite groups of Lie type.   Lots of literature out there.

Answer (score 1):

The computer algebra system [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) implements the
recursion formulas for the numbers of conjugacy classes from Macdonald's paper
cited in Nick Gill's answer. This covers the groups
${\rm GL}(n,q)$, ${\rm GU}(n,q)$, ${\rm SL}(n,q)$, ${\rm SU}(n,q)$,
${\rm PGL}(n,q)$, ${\rm PGU}(n,q)$, ${\rm PSL}(n,q)$ and ${\rm PSU}(n,q)$
for positive integers $n$ and prime powers $q$.

Some examples:

```
gap> List([2,3,4,5,7,8,9,11,13,16],q->NrConjugacyClassesPSL(3,q));
[ 6, 12, 10, 30, 22, 72, 90, 132, 64, 94 ]
gap> List([2,3,4,5,7,8,9,11,13,16],q->NrConjugacyClassesPSU(3,q));
[ 6, 14, 22, 14, 58, 28, 92, 48, 184, 274 ]
gap> NrConjugacyClassesPSL(3,2^128);
38597363079105398474523661669562635951203422344187167500973652871781632617134
gap> NrConjugacyClassesPSU(3,NextPrimeInt(10^15));
333333333333358333333333333806
gap> NrConjugacyClassesPSL(48,43);
10117782215999949055454469829685675266925185945227906522217956917437261029288
gap> NrConjugacyClassesPSU(45,49);
47750910568826421436319984311888622181462015639973663869365087657134297408
```